# Unable to use JavaGD package with R

Tags: r

I am trying to use JavaGD package with R. Few days ago with older version of R (2.13.xx) it seem working fine. Then I started getting the "jvm.dll cannot be found..." error. So I searched some forums and found that installing the latest version of R helped some people. So now I have 2.14.x version of R.

But I am still not able to use JavaGD. I am able to install rJava, though. When I do `library(JavaGD)`, the error I am getting is this:

```
> library(JavaGD)
Error in library(JavaGD) : 
  package ‘JavaGD’ does not have a NAMESPACE and should be re-installed
```

I found a bug report [here](https://www.rforge.net/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257), which is quite recent (only 10 days old). So not sure if this is a common issue. As the person over this link has said, I also re-installed the JavaGD and deleted the R directory for the older version from my machine.

My machine config is this:

- Windows XP SP3
- R 2.14.1 (11-22-2011)

I am anyways new to R, so don't know much. Any idea why is this happening? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I have already tried this answer on one of the forum:

```
That means you have a JavaGD installation in one of your libraries that 
has been installed with R < 2.14.0 but you are trying to use it with R 
 >= 2.14.0. 

Uwe Ligges
```

And it does NOT seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does - it's just that you probably have multiple installations of `JavaGD` and updating the wrong one. Check your `.libPaths()` and remove `JavaGD` from all libraries listed there, then re-install.

Comment: Yes, I have already removed the JavaGD from the .libPaths(), which is `C:/Program Files/R/R-2.14.1/library` in my case. Now, I cannot see any folder called `JavaGD`. Then, I re-installed it from a local zip file downloaded from CRAN website. I am still getting the same error. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: One more thing I noticed, for the sake of sanity, I tried to update the rJava package. When I installed it, this was printed on console: `package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`. But when I install JavaGD, this never comes up.

Comment: I have also noticed that the MD5 and NAMESPACE files are **NOT** present in the archive and the library directory.

Comment: .. which proves that you have the wrong file. Please make sure you get it from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/JavaGD_0.5-5.zip

Comment: I was using the zip from the same site, which did not have these two files. Now when I downloaded this archive again, I can see the NAMESPACE and MD5 files. And it is working! Have no idea about the previous archive which I downloaded on may be 12/29 or 12/20 2011. Anyways, thanks a lot!